# Spring Integration - kafka Outbound adapter not taking topic value exposed as spring bean

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-annotations

I have successfully integrated kafka outbound channle adapter with fixed topic name. Now, i want to make the topic name configurable and hence, want to expose it via application properties.

application.properties contain one of the following entry:

```
kafkaTopic:testNewTopic
```

My configuration class looks like below:

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${kafkaTopic}")
    private String kafkaTopicName;

    @Bean
    public String getTopic(){
    return kafkaTopicName;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");//this.brokerAddress);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        // set more properties
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }
}
```

and in my si-config.xml, i have used the following (ex: topic="getTopic") :

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
        auto-startup="true" sync="true" channel="inputToKafka" topic="getTopic">
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

However, the configuration is unable to pick up the topic name when exposed via bean. But it works fine when i hard code the value of the topic name.

Can someone please suggest what i am doing wrong here?

Does `topic` within kafka outbound channel accept the value referred as bean?

How do i externalize it as every application using my utility will supply different kafka topic names

Answer (score 0):

The `topic` attribute is for string value.

However it supports property placeholder resolution:

```
topic="${kafkaTopic}"
```

and also SpEL evaluation for aforementioned bean:

```
topic="#{getTopic}"
```

Just because this is allowed by the XML parser configuration.

However you may pay attention that `KafkaTemplate`, which you inject into the `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>` has `defaultTopic` property. Therefore you won't need to worry about that XML.

And one more option available for you is Spring Integration Annotations configuration. Where you can define a `@ServiceActivator` for the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` `@Bean`:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputToKafka")
@Bean
KafkaProducerMessageHandler kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter() {
     kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter adapter = new kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter( kafkaTemplate());
     adapter.setSync(true);
     adapter.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression(this.kafkaTopicName));
     return adapter;
}
```